# Error while Accessing link obtained by Dtale

Tags: pandas, visualization

I am trying to use `dtale` auto EDA package and I'm running into the following error :-
[image]

Code used :-

```
!pip install -U dtale
import dtale
import dtale.app as dtale_app
dtale.show(df)
```

I'm using Google Collab.
How do I access the URL without this error, tried many ways from other answers nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem . For anyone else facing the same issue.

`dtale_app.USE_COLAB = True`